# How to alter touchpad settings on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04?

Tags: gnome, touchpad, configuration, customization, gsettings

After upgrading to Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20 I have found that if I tap my touchpad it clicks which is something I do not want due to a faulty touchpad, previously I was able to disable this through the `gnome-control-center`, but seemingly there is no way to do this any more through there, so how do I do it? Also, even though it is set to `false` in `gsettings` and the `dconf-editor` seemingly for some reason somewhere in the system it is also set to `true` as it is behaving as such. I am also unable to set natural scrolling or any of the other touchpad settings seemingly, why not?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6: No need, I solved it!

Comment: This is not universal. With libinput tapping is disabled by default. But it is possible to do it with xorg-synaptics as well. But libinput is good either way. But unity-control-center does not have settings for it yet.

Comment: @Pilot6 I don't see any package `xorg-synaptics`. My `apt-cache search xorg-synaptics` returns nothing. I have all repositories enabled and sources list updated

Comment: @Pilot6: I don't know which version you're running, but I can't find such a package in the Xenial repositories.

Comment: There is no such package. In Ubuntu it is `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`. It is installed by default. But `libinput` overrides it if installed.

Comment: @Pilot6 Are you telling about `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`?

Comment: @Pilot6 Oh.. its says its already installed. then it was present when I had the same problem.

Comment: Yes it is installed. If you do not have `libinput` you can disable tapping too. But `libinput` is better than `synaptics` either way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To be able to set these settings through Terminal or through the `gnome-control-center` you need to make sure that you have `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` installed. It appears to be a bug that it is not already installed by default, in order to install simply run:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-libinput
```

After doing so and then logging out and in again you will find new settings in the `gnome-control-center`'s Mouse & Touchpad settings:

[image: New Mouse & Touchpad settings]

You should now also be able to set the touchpad settings through the `dconf-editor` and `gsettings` in Terminal.

---

Related: [LP Bug #1586657](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gsettings-desktop-schemas/+bug/1586657)

Comment: Works perfectly

Comment: You probably do not need to, you should be able to set `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method none` anyway.  In the same key, other settings are stored.

Comment: @JacobVlijm: I tested that already, if you set any of the settings through `gsettings` or `dconf-editor` it has no effect whatsoever unless you install that package. It's a bug, I've even linked the relevant bug report. It should work as you said, but it doesn't without that package.

Comment: I see you've posted duplicate answers. One of these is a dupe, therefore. Care to flag :)?

Comment: @RolandiXor: I voted to close the other one as a duplicate of this one because if you look at the question this one is more broad and the other one fits into it.

Comment: I hope that I understanding you correctly, I assume you mean to flag the question and not the answer?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda yes.

Answer (score -3):

I just installed gnome-control-center in Unity, and the tap-to-click check box is there, just to the left of two finger scroll and natural scrolling.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What version of the `gnome-control-center` did you install? There is no such option in the GNOME 3.20 one that I am running.

Comment: Hmm... I guess I just installed the "default" one.

    sudo apt install gnome-control-center

Comment: Yes, I know, it's the one the standard repos, but they do not have the latest one, if you want the latest you have to add the Ubuntu GNOME (semi-unofficial, but maintained by those who maintain all of Ubuntu GNOME) `ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging` and `ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3` PPAs.

Comment: I understand that this should work on Unity too, so if you really want to help you can install it, but I think that this has to do not with the `gnome-control-center`, but rather some `gsettings` bug because it's set manually to the correct thing, but something seems to be ignore that.

Comment: The problem has now been solved (as you can see by my answer) so please delete your answer.