# How can I permanently enable and disable the touchpad in Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS?

Tags: gnome, xorg, touchpad, dell

I have Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS installed on a Dell XPS 13, and I want to disable the touchpad.

The Dell XPS 13 does not have a key combination for enabling and disabling the touchpad. Unfortunately, also the GNOME settings for mouse and touchpad do not provide any means to enable and disable the touchpad. The accepted answer to [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/778716/how-to-alter-touchpad-settings-on-ubuntu-gnome-16-04) says that I need to install `xserver-xorg-input-libinput`. However, `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-libinput` fails with the following error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-input-libinput : Depends: xorg-input-abi-22
                               Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Apparently, `xorg-input-abi-22` does not exist in the package archives.

I am able to enable and disable the touchpad with `synclient`, but I would like to have an approach that keeps the state of the touchpad among reboots.

Comment: Umm... does the *touchpad toggle button* in **Settings > Mouse & Touchpad** not work?

Comment: There is no such button. The only things that are there are the general settings (choice of primary key, double click speed) and the mouse settings (pointer speed).

Comment: I see. I have one such button in 17.04 GNOME and it works (haven't checked whether it remembers the state after reboot though). But I don't remember if I installed any extra package(s) for that.

Comment: If you used the 16.04.2 or 16.04.3 image the you're using the hwe xserver. If so then you'd need to stick with that. In this case you'd want  `xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-16.04`  & after installing that, (if not already installed), you'd remove the `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-16.04` package. Then reboot.

Comment: I did what you suggested. The mouse settings (pointer speed) were replaced by touchpad settings (pointer speed, press to click, scrolling with two fingers, natural scrolling). No possibility to disable the touchpad though.

Answer (score 1):

for disable and enable touchpad, first see id of your touchpad using this command :

```
xinput list
```

this exmaple for the output , and look ad the id of your touchpad :
[image]

then , you can use this command to show all available command :

```
xinput list-props "your-touchpad-id"
```

this output for my touchpad

[image]

and finally , you can disable your touchpad using this command :

```
xinput set-prop "your-touchpad-id" "Device Enabled" 0
```

and this command if you want enable the touchpad :

```
xinput set-prop "your-touchpad-id" "Device Enabled" 1
```

It's work for me, hope this will help you.

**EDIT 1:**

to make it disable on **reboot** or **startup**
open startup application on your unity dash, then **click add**, new pop up window will appear, then fill like this :

> Nane : disable touchpad (or whatever you want)
>
> command : xinput set-prop "your-touchpad-id" "Device Enabled" 0
>
> comment : this command to disable touchpad at startup (or whatever you want)

take a look at this picture :
[image]

hope this will work for you too..

Comment: With this method, the touchpad does not stay disabled among reboots, does it?

Comment: take look at my answer, I have been updated my answer, hope it will help you

Comment: Hmm, I would like the system to remember the state among reboots; so if the touchpad was disabled before the reboot, it should be disabled afterwards, but if it was enabled before, it should be enabled afterwards. I thought there must be a dconf setting for this, but so far, I could not find such a setting. Note that I use GNOME, not Unity.

Answer (score -1):

Open terminal (or menu) and type: `dconf-editor`. When it opens you go to: org > gnome > desktop > touchpad > tap-to-click, and check the box to the right of the previous menu. Now you can use the click with the touchpad.

Comment: Please write your answer in English.