# ASUS N580VD-DM129T with several problems on Ubuntu Gnome 16.04

Tags: dual-boot, gnome, touchpad, configuration, asus

I installed [Ubuntu GNOME](https://ubuntugnome.org/download/) on my ASUS N580VD-DM129T, with Dual Boot alongside Windows 10. The OS's share a 128gb SSD and I have a 1TB HDD in the notebook as well.

I am very frustrated that I have been experiencing several problems in the installation of Linux and have to search a lot in the web to configure and fix many kinds of different annoying things. Here's a list including some of them:

- Selection of filenames has bad contrast

[image: Selected]
[image: Not selected]

- Hibernate and sleep options missing
- Configuration options of touchpad missing - https://askubuntu.com/a/778766/315699

Current configuration window
[image: Current configuration window]
Missing touchpad configuration part
[image: Missing touchpad configuration part]

- Tap function in touchpad not working
- Weak wifi signal - https://appuals.com/increase-signal-strength-weak-wifi-signal-linux/ or https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_network_configuration#iwlwifi
- Missing "new file" option in the floating menu when pressing right mouse button inside a folder - ["Create new document" - right-click option missing in Ubuntu GNOME](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777711/create-new-document-right-click-option-missing-in-ubuntu-gnome)
- After some time turned on, the system starts to become slow. Only normalizes when I restart gnome shell by pressing Alt+F2, typing r, then pressing ENTER.
- Battery icon never shows as 100%, although being charged
  [image: Battery icon]
- Error on startup

[image: Error message]
[image: Error details]

- Takes more time to boot and to shutdown than Windows 10, which is the inverse of what used to be in my old notebook.

Is there anything I can do that could fix many of these issues at once? Or will I really have to invest many hours in forums trying to configure the system? May it be that my notebook is not compatible with Linux?

Comment: Hello, you should try with the latest version of Ubuntu (17.10). A lot of things improved from the 16.04 version.

Comment: So you mean this is what is expected from 16.04? Everyone installs it and configure all these silly things?

Comment: Hi, of course things improve over time. I had the same problem you had with my Dell XPS 13, after 17.10 everything was simpler. If you have a very common computer you may have less issues than with a more exclusive model. I strongly recommend you to try with 17.10.

Comment: Ok, I will think about it! It's just that installing the OS and all the programs again is also a pain...

Comment: @PhilippeDelteil I recently ran Ubuntu 18.04 from a USB stick. It solves some of these problems, but the worst of them is still there. Wi-fi signals are very weak:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014198/how-to-make-intel-wi-fi-signal-stronger-in-ubuntu-gnome-16-04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a single fix for all the problems. But here's a list of the individual solutions:

## Selection of filenames has bad contrast

Couldn't solve this one in Ubuntu 16.04, but it is solved in Ubuntu 18.04

## Hibernate and sleep options missing

Actually, if you press Alt, the shutdown button [image: shutdown button] turns into a sleep button [image: sleep button]

## Configuration options of touchpad missing and Tap function in touchpad not working

Solution for both here: https://askubuntu.com/a/778766/315699

## Weak wifi signal

I didn't find a solution for this. And it is not solved nor in Ubuntu 17.10, nor in Ubuntu 18.04.
Check these links for more information
https://appuals.com/increase-signal-strength-weak-wifi-signal-linux/

or

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_network_configuration#iwlwifi

or this question I made:
[How to make Intel wi-fi signal stronger in Ubuntu Gnome 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014198/how-to-make-intel-wi-fi-signal-stronger-in-ubuntu-gnome-16-04)

## Missing "new file" option in the floating menu when pressing right mouse button inside a folder

Solution described here: ["Create new document" - right-click option missing in Ubuntu GNOME](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777711/create-new-document-right-click-option-missing-in-ubuntu-gnome)

## After some time turned on, the system starts to become slow.

Only normalizes when I restart gnome shell by pressing Alt+F2, typing r, then pressing ENTER. I haven't found anything better than this.

## Battery icon never shows as 100%, although being charged

Check here: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/10/show-battery-percentage-ubuntu-17-10/

## Takes more time to boot and to shutdown than Windows 10, which is the inverse of what used to be in my old notebook.

This is actually because Windows 10 has a new functionality called fast startup that maintains part of the system information stored for faster startup, which is somewhat similar to a hibernation. If this functionality is disabled, then the boot times are similar.

## BONUS

### Notification for caps lock key

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tsbarnes/indicator-keylock
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-keylock
```